# IE9 stop working when after click on anchor tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, anchor

I'm designing a site, that i have anchor tag styled "display: block" and contain some elements in it such as div, table, span.

it's almost fine, but in IE9 randomly when i click on this anchor tags, IE9 stop working and show this error:
[image]

some tags have href attribute "javascript:" and some other have a link in href attribute.

does anybody knows about it? what can i do?
one of them is like this:

```
            <asp:LinkButton ID="id" CssClass="Icons" runat="server" OnClick="event">
                <div class="NotHoBack">
                </div>
                <div class="HoverStyle">
                </div>
                <div class="IconImg" style="background-image: url('/url');">
                </div>

                <div class="IconBorder" >
                </div>
                <div class="IconText">
                    برنامه هفتگی
                </div>
            </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: can you jsfiddle it so we can also test it?

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net to setup a testscenario.

Comment: look at this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bTngk/)

Comment: sorry , look at this ===> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/U8F6s/1/)